# Heterogenous Recyclerview: Retain scroll position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have horizontal RecyclerViews inside a vertical Recyclerview as my HomeFragment. 
[image]

And everytime I navigate to a different fragment by clicking an item in the horizontal RecyclerView and go back to the HomeFragment, my horizontal RecyclerViews are scrolled to the first item and the last state (or scroll position) are not retained. How can I be able to achieve that when I go back to HomeFragment, the scroll position are the same as to before I navigated to a different Fragment?

I've come accross using LinearLayoutManager's `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` but this is my code, I added the horizontal recyclerviews on the `onBind()` of the vertical recyclerview and I don't know where to use those methods.

```
void onBind(HomeData data) {
    binding.setVariable(BR.homedata, data);
    binding.executePendingBindings();

    if (binding instanceof ItemMovieListBinding) {
        MoviesAdapter adapter = new MoviesAdapter(new MovieDiffCallback(), clickCallback);

        ((ItemMovieListBinding) binding).rvMovieList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));
        ((ItemMovieListBinding) binding).rvMovieList.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.submitList((List<Movie>) data.getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal#java

This might help

Answer (score -1):

You can just remember position, which user before left the screen and restore it:

```
rvMovieList.scrollToPosition(yourPosition);
```

Or you can init your adapter and recyclerView in `onActivityCreated`. That will help you to avoid the recreation of views.